# c# how to get the values next to checked datagridview checkboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with CheckBox column, my question is how do I get the data next to a checked checkboxes and assign them to a variables in array?

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {            
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["chkBoxColumn"].Value = true) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            }
        }   
    }
```

It prints the last checked item over and over.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

        {
            if (bool.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["chkBoxColumn"].Value.ToString()) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

and i'm getting a null reference exception using this.

Comment: Do you mean you want the value of a certain column in a row where a checkbox has the value `true`?

Comment: Why you are trying to handle `CellValueChanged`? Are you going to show the message box by change in every checkbox?

Comment: @Huntt Yes, but I want let the user to tick many checkboxes. How am I gonna be able to get all those values next to checked checkboxes?

Comment: @RezaAghaei actually I want to get every values next to a checked checkbox and assign them to variables, can you suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: @Dhenz I've posted an answer that does the job, but I can't imagine this is the intended behaviour. Can you try to elaborate what you really need? Also it would be handy to just use named columns instead of `Cells[1]`.

Comment: You can use linq to find those values simply like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48063984/3110834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
Question got changed, so tweaked the code so that the values get put into a list.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{            
    List<string> someList = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        var cell = row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

        if (Convert.ToBoolean(cell.Value) == true)
        {
            if (cell.State != DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
            {
                someList.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        else if (cell.State == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
        {
            someList.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        }
    }   
}
```

This might do the trick for you, however you'll get a popup every time a user ticks a checkbox, and you'll get as many popup as there are checkboxes that are `true`.

Comment: @Dhenz Edited code so that the values of a ticked checkbox get added to a list, this updates the list when a checkbox get ticked on the grid. Please notice that the event changed to `CellContentClick`

Comment: Is there a way to save it to an array? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Dhenz yeah after you saved all the items to the list, you can just call `var array = someList.ToArray()` and you will have a string array.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in the line

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

`e.RowIndex` points to the changed row

it should be:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        var row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i]
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["chkBoxColumn"].Value = true) == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Also, note that you're getting error in your second example because some row is containing a null value in the checkbox column.

`Convert.ToBoolean(null)` returns false

But `bool.Parse(null)` throws an exception

Comment: You are using an `foreach` with a `for` syntax, don't think that's gonna work. And a checkbox column can't contain the value null, just true of false.

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this ?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{            
    Stringbuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["chkBoxColumn"].Value = true) == true)
        {
            text.Append(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());                
        }
    }   

    MessageBox.Show(text.ToString());
}
```

**EDIT**: the question has changed from showing the values to saving them into an array, so I need to change my answer also

Suppose you want all values for Cell[1] saved into an array
and suppose that cell is of type integer.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{            
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["chkBoxColumn"].Value = true) == true)
        {
            list.Add(int.Parse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()));                
        }
    }   

    // you now have all values saved into the list
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at row sir/maam cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of 'type datagridviewrow'

Comment: @Dhenz I have added to my answer, hope it can help you

Comment: when I tick a checkbox, it immediately checks all the checkboxes, what's causing this?

Comment: @Dhenz How can I know ? show us all relevant code else noone can guess what can cause this

Comment: @Dhenz Does this also happens without the CellValueChanged event ? IF not, what code is currently in that event ? Are there other events coupled ?

Comment: Yes, i tried moving it to the button1_Click but same result when I pressed the button. I have this    private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            {
                dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can put the code in a button click and find checked values this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkedValues = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells["Your CheckBox Column Name"].Value == true)
        .Select(row => string.Format("{0}", row.Cells["The Other Column Name"].Value))
        .ToList();

    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", checkedValues));
}
```

Comment: Can you help me get the values and assign it into an array?

Comment: `checkedValues` is a list of those values. If for any reason you need an array instead of a `List`, then simply use `ToArray` method.